# comparing int float python problem

Tags: python, divide-by-zero

I have this code:

```
def fit(self,p1,p2,w):
    p=p1    
    m=self.bit(p,w)
    if p1.y!=p2.y:
        if m&0x30:
            p.y=w.y1 if m&0x10 else w.y2-1
            try:
                p.x=int((p.y-p2.y)*(p1.x-p2.x)/(p1.y-p2.y)+p2.x)
            except Exception,e:
                print e
                print p1.y!=p2.y        
                print p1.y,p2.y
```

The output is:

```
cannot convert float NaN to integer  
False  
199 199.0
```

I have no idea why `p1.y!=p2.y` evaluates to true and then in the exception it evaluates to false

I'm running python 2.6.6

Comment: Because you change `p1.y` (via `p.y`) here? `p.y=w.y1 if m&0x10 else w.y2-1`

Comment: thanks Amber, completely missed that :|

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing `0/0`!

```
# (p.y-p2.y)*(p1.x-p2.x)
x = p.y - p2.y
x = 199 - 199.0 = 0
x1 = p1.x-p2.x
0 * x1 = 0* p1.x - 0* p2.x
```

This means

```
(p.y-p2.y)*(p1.x-p2.x) = 0
```

Now we are devising 0 by this:

```
#(p1.y-p2.y)
p1.y-p2.y
x = p.y - p2.y
x = 199 - 199.0 = 0
```

So in this case you are trying to do `0/0`

Then at the end of the whole thing you try to add `p2.x` and i believe thats why you get the error `cannot convert float NaN to integer` and not `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`

Its really easy to solve. change `if p1.y!=p2.y:` line 4 to `If p1.y-p2.y != 0:`